# Alignment with brackets

Tags: align

I am having problem in the align environment when I have brackets. Here is my example.

```
\begin{align}
A& = B~~~&+c~~-D\\
E& = F&+G-H
\end{align}
```

However, a similar problem I have with the use of brackets in an equation is below which is **giving me an error**

```
\begin{align}
A& = \left(B~~~&+c~~-D\right)\\
E& = \left(F&+G-H \right)
\end{align}
```

Could some provide assistance with the second command. I need to align about the + or - signs.  In summary, how can I make the second code work properly (when we have brackets in the equation).  Here I don't find the use of `\left.` or `\right.` as the brackets are in the same line.

Appreciate your efforts.

Thanks.

Comment: There is also a second alignment issue in this question not present in the potential duplicate.

Comment: The answer in the duplicate question does address this question as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want multiple alignment spots, try using the `alignat` environment like such:

```
\begin{alignat}{4}
A& = \bigl(B & + & c-D\bigr)\\
E& = \bigl(F & + & G-H \bigr)
\end{alignat}
```

Does this achieve the desired result you are looking for?

As David Carlisle points out, it may be better to use `\bigl(\bigr)` so there isn't a size issue.

Comment: bettet to use \bigl( \bigr) than \left(\right. \left. \right) as otherwise there is no guarantee the brackets will match in size

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I will make the correction.

Answer (score 5):

The commands `\left...\right` must occur on the same side of an aligment, i.e. in one "cell".  In this case you must use the specific sizing commands `\bigl...\bigr` or their variants `\Bigl`, `\biggl`, `\Biggl` etc.

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{alignat}{2}
A& = \bigl(B&&+c-D\bigr)\\
E& = \bigl(F&&+G-H \bigr)
\end{alignat}
\end{document}
```

Note that I have used the `alignat` environment rather than `align`.  Multiple columns in `align` are designed for aligning separate equations, such as

[image: Sample align]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
  x &=y  &  p&=q, \\
  X &= Y &  P&=Q.
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

On the other hand `alignat` provides multiple alignment points in the same equation.  In both cases one usually has an odd number of `&`'s and groups are aligned pairwise "right & left", thus the column of `p''s is right aligned.  For`alignat`you have to say how many such "pairs" there are: this is equal to "(number of &'s + 1)/2".  Thus the argument to`alignat`in my top example with three ampersands is`2`.

Finally you should also be aware spacing around relation signs at such alignment points.  Consider:

[image: Sample mixed alignat]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{alignat}{4}
  x &=y  &&+ (y-1)^3&+&(y+1)^7 &{}-{}&1, \\
  X &= Y &&+  Y^3&+&Y^7 &{}-{}&1.
\end{alignat}

\end{document}
```

Looking at the columns of relation signs, note that the spacing around the first two columns with `&=` and `&&+` is correct, while that for the third with `&+&` is too tight.  In the forth column I have placed extra empty groups `{}-{}` to correct this.